# @ConditionalOnProperty props not detected by configuration processor

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

I'm working on a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA, managing properties in the **`application.yml`** file. While I can easily find usages of properties annotated with **`@Value`**, I'm struggling to locate usages of properties annotated with **`@ConditionalOnProperty`**. Manually searching for the property names is time consuming. How can I efficiently identify and navigate to usages of properties annotated with **`@ConditionalOnProperty`** within IntelliJ IDEA? I've checked the documentation and would appreciate any insights or alternative approaches.

Comment: It's a known issue in IDE. Please follow the related case on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-318132